# CORS error when using Text to speech (TTS) azure cognitive service

Tags: azure, cors, azure-cognitive-services, django-cors-headers

I have used TTS(Text to speech ) cognitive service from azure, library used is python azure-cognitiveservices-speech == 1.17.0 I initially tried and deployed this in Heroku cloud and it works as intended.

However, when I deployed this in VM I am getting a CORS error. My CORS is set properly and I have tried allowing all hosts ('*') that also has not helped (my backend is Django)

```
speech_key = settings.SPEECH_KEY
service_region = settings.SERVICE_REGION
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "ar-SA-Naayf"
filename = './audio.wav'
filename = filename.replace('.wav', '_' + str(random.randint(10, 10000)) + '.wav')
audio_file_path = Path(str(filename)).resolve()
audio_config = AudioOutputConfig(filename=str(audio_file_path))

# Creates a speech synthesizer using the default speaker as audio output.
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

# Receives a text from console input.
text = "Hello World"
result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
```

In my prod.py for CORS

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['api.abc.com']
```

In my settings.py for CORS

```
# Cors Header
# Allowed cors headers
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'Cache-Control', 'X-Requested-With')
```

Error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.abc.com/tts/' from origin 'https://api-dev.abc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any setting that I should be looking into or configuration change?

Comment: There are plenty of different errors with CORS. Which one exactly do you get. And please also show your CORS configuration on the server

Comment: @derpirscher Where can we see CORS details in cognitive serve or do we need to configure CORS explicitly in azure cognitive service.

Comment: No, the CORS error doesn't have anything to do with the azure service. It's between your client at `api-dev.abc.om` and your own backend at `api.abc.com`. But htere is an error with your allowed hosts. You are allowing `api.abc.com`. From the errormessage I can see, that that is your backend server. But you need to allow the url of the frontend, which -- from the errormessage -- seems to be `api-dev.abc.com`